# How to remove spaces onPaste in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How can I remove space from a string when pasted in a textfield in Reactjs using `onPaste event` so that the final string that appears inside the text field has no spaces in between.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<input placeholder="Enter your First Name" onPaste={(event) => this.onFirstNamePaste(event)}/>
```

event handler:

```
onFirstNamePaste(event){
    var text = event.clipboardData.getData('Text')
    this.value = text.replace(/\s/g,'');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 onFirstNamePaste(event){
    var text = event.clipboardData.getData('Text')
    this.value = text.split(' ').join('');
 }
```

Comment: This removes the spaces, but same needs to be reflected in the text field. Is there a way using which I can directly set the value of the field from where this event has been triggered.

Comment: You can access DOM evement via event.target.value = text.split(' ').join('');

Answer (score 0):

Use the ref attribute for the input element,

```
<input 
    ref={(nameInput) => { this.nameInput = nameInput; }}
    placeholder="Enter your First Name"
    onPaste={(event) => this.onFirstNamePaste(event)}
/>
```

And then inside the function,

```
onFirstNamePaste(event){
    const text = event.clipboardData.getData('Text')
    this.nameInput.value = text.split(' ').join('');
}
```

---

You can also use the component state to track the changes in the input and update the state to reflect the changes.

```
<input 
    value={this.state.nameValue}
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ nameValue: e.target.value }) }
    placeholder="Enter your First Name"
    onPaste={(event) => this.onFirstNamePaste(event)}
/>
```

In the paste function,

```
onFirstNamePaste(event){
    const text = event.clipboardData.getData('Text')
    const value = text.split(' ').join('');
    this.setState({ nameValue: value });
}
```